# 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer' -- WRS2 package

Tags: r, list, object, types, integer

I come across the below error when trying to use a function of WRS2 package.

> Error in sequence.default(piece, ...) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Below is the code. Percentile_rank, grade_level, and books_quantile's data types are numeric data. Percentile rank's value is from 1-99, grade_level from 1-10, and books_quantile from 1-3. And each observation reflects one student's grade, their test score's percentile rank, and the quartile of number of books they received.

```
library(WRS2)
pbad2way(percentile_rank~ grade_level + books_quantile + grade_level*books_quantile,
         data = read)
```

A snapshot of data frame "read" is as below (I removed some variables that are sensitive/not relevant)

```
tibble [20,903 x 21] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id                    : chr [1:20903] "4886656" "4648093" "4544642" "4487743" ...
 $ school_year_key          : chr [1:20903] "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" ...
 $ grade_key                : chr [1:20903] "736" "738" "738" "738" ...
 $ grade_level              : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ percentile_rank          : num [1:20903] 43 97 84 23 27 5 84 6 1 21 ...
 $ books_count              : num [1:20903] 55 46 43 56 57 55 49 42 51 57 ...
 $ discipline               : chr [1:20903] "Reading" "Reading" "Reading" "Reading" ...
 $ books_quantile           : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 ...
```

When I used traceback() after the error, it says below:

```
8: sequence.default(piece, ...)
7: .fun(piece, ...)
6: (function (i) 
   {
       piece <- pieces[[i]]
       if (.inform) {
           res <- try(.fun(piece, ...))
           if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
               piece <- paste(utils::capture.output(print(piece)), 
                   collapse = "\n")
               stop("with piece ", i, ": \n", piece, call. = FALSE)
           }
       }
       else {
           res <- .fun(piece, ...)
       }
       progress$step()
       res
   })(10L)
5: loop_apply(n, do.ply)
4: llply(.data = pieces, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress, 
       .inform = .inform, .parallel = .parallel, .paropts = .paropts)
3: alply(nfac1, 1, sequence)
2: unlist(alply(nfac1, 1, sequence), use.names = FALSE)
1: pbad2way(percentile_rank ~ grade_level + books_quantile + grade_level * 
       books_quantile, data = read)
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question with the results of `str(read)` please

Comment: @user20650: hi i just add the str(read). thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't reproduce your error using the `goggles` datasets after changing the variables class to match yours and using tibbles. Could you try running `traceback()` right after your code errors to get an idea where the error occurs

Comment: @user20650: I just added the result after traceback(), thank you!

Comment: @user20650: sorry just edited the result after traceback a few seconds ago

Comment: Thanks. I think it could be an issue with your data -- I can reproduce the error with `data(goggles) ; goggles$alcohol[goggles$gender == "Male" & goggles$alcohol == "None"] <- "2 Pints" ; pbad2way(attractiveness ~ gender*alcohol, data = goggles)` . Note there is a zero cell in the interaction -- `with(goggles, table(gender, alcohol))`. Is it similar in your data? -- try running `with(read, table(grade_level, books_quantile))`

Comment: oh yea i found some zero cells! I tried to remove the whole grade level 9 as below. but when I tried with(read, table(grade_level, books_quantile)) the grade level 9 is still there, this is what I did:

keep <- c('K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8')
read1 <- read[read$grade_level %in% keep,]
with(read1, table(grade_level, books_quantile))

Comment: Try `read1 <- droplevels(read[read$grade_level %in% keep,])` . btw I do not know if the fact that this method implementation doesn't work with zero cells is a programming issue (if it is expected that it should) or statistical (i.e. there are reasons that it shouldn't work)

Comment: oh there was not the same error anymore, but it has another statistic error that I think is inherently because of the dataset. thank you so much for your help!